# Should I edit a question if it has only one spelling mistake in title

Tags: discussion, edits

Recently while searching for questions on "Database cache", I misspelled it as "Databse cache" in search box, and i got a list of many questions which had only one spelling mistake. i,e OP wrote "Database" as "Databse".

I know that 6 characters limit is for editing questions, but for editing title there is no limit.

Will my Edit will be rejected if I edit only one word in the title OR is it OK to do so?

[Example Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34653913/3603374)

Answer (score 6):

You'd be welcome to suggest an edit, but at the same time you should look into addressing the *other* problems in the question.

i.e

- the bold text for no apparent reason
- the performance tag which isn't directly relevant to the question being asked
- the quote blocks instead of just simple lists...

Essentially, whilst you may start the post to fix a single thing, you should look at sorting out the rest of it at the same time, if its the only thing wrong with the post then sure, there isn't any harm in suggesting the edit.

One other thing to add is that you shouldn't go looking for things to edit, there isn't much to be gained from editing old posts for simple mistakes, it has adverse affects such as making the question appear active

Comment: Ugh, the superfluous blockquotes. You might also mention, though, that this is basically polishing a turd. The question is low quality and arguably off-topic.

Comment: @CodyGray - I didn't know enough about PHP to be able to tell if it was a genuine question but I agree, no amount of editing can make some questions any better

Comment: To be honest, I don't know anything about PHP either, but I don't see anything about PHP in the question other than the tags. It is a database question, far as I can tell, asking what the "fastest" option is.

Comment: This answer is FALSE,  I am NOT "welcome to suggest an edit [of a single spelling error assuming the correction is less than 5 characters]".

Comment: @Andrew it's not false. You simply didn't read it: *"whilst you may start the post to fix a single thing, you should look at sorting out the rest of it at the same time"* - fixing a single spelling error is not fixing the whole post.